# Interpretation of Multiple run LSTM Model Vs Single run

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm

I am new to Machine Learning & Deep Learning.

**Trained the model for single run (One time) :**

I trained my `LSTM classifier model for one time (single run)` and plotted the graph as below.
I checked for `metrics (accuracy, precision, recall)`, which are convincing for both training, validation and testing.

[image]

**Trained the model for multiple runs (5 times) :**

While LSTM are stochastic, I would like to understand the behavior of  `train_loss & valid_loss` of LSTM. So i `ran the LSTM model 5 times` and   plotted the `train_loss & valid_loss` in a single graph as below

[image]

**Questions**

> What can i interpret or understand from the above pictures ?
>
> Whether my model trained properly or not ? If not, what were the reasons for
> improper training ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have a solution which solves my problem, it may differ w.r.t the data we deal with and other requirement.**

I have used 2 Drop out layers of 10%, just to regularize my model.
Since I have only 2200 parameters in my model, the usage of drop outs results only limited amount of data to be learnt.

> So on avoiding the drop out, i can get my loss & val_loss follows a
>   pattern.

[image]